# Can't read csv files from dplyr package

Tags: r

I tried to change location using `setwd()`. I can use `ggplot2` package and this package working good. So I think my com can't load csv files from `dplyr` package. and The picture below is my console picture. Where I should fix?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example:

```
library(tidyverse)
bison <- read_csv('bison_orangecounty.csv')

class(bison)

str(bison)
head(bison)
tail(bison)
```

Comment: okay... I'll try like this